# Share a file between a thread and my main

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

I have a file that I want to declare in a main, but modify in a thread.

I declare in my `MainWindow` header file `std::ofstream file;` .

Then I try to initialize it my constructor of my `MainWindow.cpp` like this : `file("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);`

The function in the thread is static:

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.

        ref_bool_Server = true;
        fichier ("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
        m_t1 = std::thread(lancerServeur, std::ref(ref_bool_Server), std::ref(lancerEnregistrement));

        // Je sauvegarde ma main window
        m_psMainWindow = this;

    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
        ref_bool_Server = false;
        m_t1.join();
    }


        void MainWindow::lancerServeur(std::atomic<bool>& boolServer, std::atomic<bool>& lancerEnregistrement){
            serveur s;//J'instancie un serveur
            StructureSupervision::T_StructureSupervision* bufferStructureRecu;
        while(boolServer){
            bufferStructureRecu = s.receiveDataUDP();
            if(bufferStructureRecu != NULL){
               m_psMainWindow->emit_signal_TrameRecu( bufferStructureRecu );
            }
            if(lancerEnregistrement){
                fichier << bufferStructureRecu->SystemData._statutGroundFlight;
            }
        }

    }
```

The de claration of the ofstream is false (probably synthaxic), and I don't know how to use this file in a static function.

Comment: Could you throw us some code?

Comment: dont you mean file.open(same args)? I think the constructor is only taking the file buffer not the same arguments as file.open

Comment: @Mayerz I give you everything there's just 2 line ...

Comment: Where are you declaring (or defining) the `file` object? In the global namespace, other namespace, or as member of a class?

Comment: `static std::ofstream file;` && `file = std::ofstream ("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);`

Comment: @Blacktempel Well it do something, but create more error : use of deleted function 'std::basic_ofstream<char>& std::basic_ofstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ofstream<char>&)'

Comment: @Blacktempel This only works in C++11.  Not all compilers are up to date here.

Comment: @Blacktempel And of course, it's probably not the correct solution to his larger problem, which he doesn't reveal to us.

Comment: @JamesKanze Isn't the question tagged C++11 ?

Comment: @Blacktempel can just call [`file.open(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) rather than assign to it.  Still, it's not credible that Evans wants the file declared `static` in a header... that's hideous.  The implication is usage from multiple translation units, which means it should be declared `extern` and defined in any one translation unit.

Comment: @Blacktempel I missed that.  Still, if he's getting an error with the statement, he's either mistyped (or typed it in the wrong place) what you're suggesting, or his compiler isn't up to date in this regard (which is what his error message suggests).  As we all know, no compiler currently supports all of C++11, so we can only use it piecemeal.  (And of course, just calling `file.open` would be a simpler solution, in the unlikely case that this is really what he wants.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking, you can't *call* a constructor, at least
not in the sense you mean.  (An expression such as
`std::ofstream( "test.txt" )` looks like you're calling
a constructor, but the standard calls it an explicit type
conversion.)  The constructor is called when you define
a variable, e.g. in the statement `std::ofstream file;` (which
calls the default constructor).  When you write `file(...)`, the
compiler looks for an overloaded `operator()` in the type of
`file`; there isn't one, so it is an error.

It's not clear what you actually want to do, so it's difficult
to provide exact advice.  One thing is sure, however: you do
*not* want a definition of a variable (e.g.
`std::ofstream file;` at namespace scope) in a header.  If you
do, that header can only be included in one source, or you'll
end up with multiple definitions.  (Such a definition would be
reasonable in a class definition in a header.)  At best, you
would want `extern std::ofstream file;` in the header, with the
definition in one (and only one) of the source files which
include that header; in the definition, you can provide
arguments which would be used for construction.  Except that
I can't think of a context where it would make sense to have an
`std::ofstream` at namespace scope.

EDIT:

From your update of the question, from the error message, it
looks like `file` is a member variable.  In that case, you
provide any arguments to the constructor in the initializer list
of the constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
    : file( "test.txt" )
{
}
```

And of course, if it is a member, you cannot access it without
having an instance of the class.  Which is not normally the case
in a static member function.

EDIT:

After your update: it's still not clear whether you want
`fichier` to be a static member or not.  Typically, there will
be only one `MainWindow` object; do both users have access to
it?  (This would normally be the preferred solution.)  If so,
there's no problem making it non-static, and initializing it as
above.  Or you could pass a reference to it (the `fichier`
member) directly to the thread.  This is the solution I would
prefer.  Alternatively, you could declare it static.  In that
case, you would need to explicitly define it in one, and only
one source file:

```
std::ofstream MainWindow::fichier;
```

And you would then open it in the constructor:

```
fichier.open( "test.txt" );
```

This could cause problems, however, if more than one instance of
`MainWindow` gets constructed.

Finally, from the code you show: only the thread actually uses
the file, so it might be preferrable to declaring it as a local
variable in the `lancerServer` function.  There's no point in
making it visible to several threads if only one is going to
access it.  If this is due to a simplification in your posted
code, and it *is* used by several threads, then you'll need to
add code to synchronize access.

Comment: I will update my post to give more info, thanks for your help.

Comment: There's only 1 instance of MainWindow, I need to declare my file in my Main and not local in my server, because in the destructor of my main, I want to delete the file if nothing is write in it. I'll try to pass an instance of my file so ...

Comment: @EvansBelloeil Anything you do after the join, you could do in the main function of the thread.  But deleting doesn't require the `ofstream`, just the name, so you could still delete after the join, in the main thread, even if the `ofstream` object were in the thread.  (If you're on Windows, of course, you'll have to ensure that the file is closed before deleting.)